# Javascript return function syntax

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a function that returns some code and am struggling to do so.

```
function getpresent (place) = {
  type: "single-stim",
  stimulus: getword(place),
  is_html: true,
  timing_stim: 250,
  timing_response: 2000,
  response_ends_trial: false,
  };
```

This is what I have right now, but it is not working. I need something like...

```
function getpresent (place) = {
   RETURN [
  type: "single-stim",
  stimulus: getword(place),
  is_html: true,
  timing_stim: 250,
  timing_response: 2000,
  response_ends_trial: false,
],  
};
```

Is this just a syntax thing? Or is what I'm trying to do just fundamentally flawed? Thanks!

Comment: You almost have it. Instead of `function getpresent (place) = {` try `function getpresent (place) { return {` and end it with a `}`

Answer (score 3):

If you like to return an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), then this would work

```
function getpresent (place) {
    return {
        type: "single-stim",
        stimulus: getword(place),
        is_html: true,
        timing_stim: 250,
        timing_response: 2000,
        response_ends_trial: false
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of mixed syntax here.

```
var getpresent = place => ({
  type: 'single-stim',
  stimulus: getword(place),
  is_html: true,
  timing_stim: 250,
  timing_response: 2000,
  response_ends_trial: false
});
```

Note, this will not work without a transpiler or with a browser that supports ES6 arrow functions. I didn't know which direction you were heading.

An array (`[ ]`) cannot contain Key/Value pairs like you have in the bottom section of code. Only objects have Key/Value Pairs (`{ }`).

Also, `RETURN` is not valid and you must use `return` in order to return from a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getpresent(place) {
  return {
    type: "single-stim",
    stimulus: getword(place),
    is_html: true,
    timing_stim: 250,
    timing_response: 2000,
    response_ends_trial: false,
  }
}
```

or with the ES6 syntax:

```
const getpresent = (place) => ({
  type: "single-stim",
  stimulus: getword(place),
  is_html: true,
  timing_stim: 250,
  timing_response: 2000,
  response_ends_trial: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `=`

proper function syntax:

```
function myFunction(param) {
    return param;  
}
```